# Magento 2.4.5 Admin goes to pub url

Tags: magento2

I have upgrade the Magento to 2.4.5 version but the URL goes to the pub folder after login in admin
Please help me with that.

Url - [site.com/project/pub/admin/tfa/tfa/requestconfig/key/8027dcadf6a2a36be58f269f90961ae4f06d50ff6f3afa3faeb947cafbf74187][1]/

Admin like this after login - https://prnt.sc/5lfEasZVd23e

Comment: Can you please tell us that your magento 2.4.5 is running fine or not. I want to use Magento 2.4.5 for my site?